# What does ゆーか mean?

Tags: meaning

> 見ず知らず子供を助けるほど、お節介と**ゆーか**、親切ってほどでもない。

What does ゆーか mean? I searched on Jisho, Weblio and Googled it, but found nothing. What does it mean? Is this some kind of abbreviation, or onomatopoeia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

とゆーか is a colloquial way of writing というか . It is mentioned as a colloquial form in the entry for というか in [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B):

> 「てゆーか」のように転訛した形で表記される場合が多い。

As well as in the [EN-JP version of Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%86%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B) and in [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%86%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B).

Comment: Is it somewhere on En-Jp Weblio? I am not feeling so good, about reading JpJp dictionary yet so I didn't search there for it, but thank you for your answer. I now have to learn what というか mean.

Comment: @SkillGG https://jisho.org/search/toiuka

Comment: I was asking about colloquial version.

Comment: @SkillGG jisho also has it https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%86%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B

Comment: ゆー is the completely standard way of saying 言う. What's colloquial is *writing* it that way.