# Meaning of XほどYほどでもない

Tags: grammar, particle-ほど

Sentence taken from [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/67817/what-does-%E3%82%86%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B-mean):

> 見ず知らずの子供を助けるほど、お節介とゆーか、親切ってほどでもない。

I'm failing miserably to understand this sentence. Writing it less colloquially we presumably get:

> 見ず知らずの子供を助けるほど、お節介というか、親切というほどでもない。

I understand ほど to mean "to the extent that/of" e.g. 昨日ほど暑くない = "to the extent of yesterday, it's not hot" = "It's not as hot as yesterday".

My guess at a translation would be roughly:

> "I'm so meddlesome that I save strange children, or rather, I don't do it out of kindness".

but I feel that would be two separate sentences: " i.e. 見ず知らず子供を助けるほど、お節介だ = "To the extent that I save strange children, I am meddlesome", and 
"というか、親切というほどでもない" = "Or rather, to the extent that it is kindness, it is not".

Something tells me I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「見ず知らずの子供を助ける**ほど**、お節介{せっかい}とゆーか、親切{しんせつ}って**ほど**でもない。」

Conclusion first.  The only reason that 「ほど」 is used twice is that this sentence is fairly informal/colloquial.  In more formal speech, it would rarely be used twice in such a short sentence.  The second 「ほど」 is the one that would be dropped in more formal speech.

So, how does one know it is informal/colloquial?  One knows by the use of 「ゆーか」 and 「って」 as you yourself seem to have noticed.  「ゆーか」 is indeed *very* informal.

The last half of the sentence could have been formed instead as:

・「---、お節介とゆーか、親切って**わけ**でもない。」 or

・「---、お節介とゆーか、親切って**ゆーこと**でもない。」

> "I am not so meddlesome or rather "kind" as to go out of my way to help children I do not (even) know."